# How to make snscrape faster?

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using snscrape for scraping data from Twitter. It usually takes 26 sec for 1000 tweets. I'm finding ways to make the function faster. Will the for loop be made more fast using numba or should I use list compression or any hardware acceleration method available or it is not possible as snscrape is generally slow? Any help will be great for me.

```
def func():

  query ="python"
  tweets=[]
  limit=10000
  for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    if len(tweets) == limit:
     break
    else:
      tweets.append([tweet.date,tweet.username,tweet.content])
  return tweets

df = pd.DataFrame(func(),columns=['Date','User','Tweet'])
print(df)
```

Comment: I assume you have not actually done any instrumentation, so you don't actually know where your time is being spent.  Without that information, you are simply shooting in the dark.  You seem to be overlooking simply network latency.  You're doing 40 requests a second.  NOTHING you can do will make the network faster.  You are not CPU-bound here.  You are I/O bound.

Comment: 40 requests per second doesn't sound right, as the TwitterSearchScraper imitates Twitter's search UI on the web, so there's more than one result per API pagination...

Comment: But yeah, ideally profile your application before you try to optimise.